# Vectorize/Accelerate looping through a struct of struct in Matlab?

Tags: r, matlab, vectorization, apply

I am looking for something similar to **sapply function** in R in Matlab.
 I have the current issue:

I have a large struct of size 1000, each one inside is a struct, that is, I have a **struct of struct**.

Each **substruct** are in the same style, that is, the same fields.

I am using a function to do something on each **substruct**

The code looks like:

```
 for i =1:length(mainStruct)
      disp(i);
      result(i) = myfunction(mainStruct(i).field(1:1000));
 end
```

In the above, **myfunction** is just a function, **mainStruct** is the **sturct of struct**, **mainStruct(i)** is accessing each **subStruct**.

I have tried **structfun**, but it only works on struct's field names, not on **struct of struct.**

**The question is how I can get rid of this loop?**

Comment: You ask to vectorize, but that would require `myfunction` to be already vectorized. Does it accept vectorized inputs? Can you pass a matrix and it will interpret each row as a vector?

Comment: have you tried to make the big struct into an array? And then you could do `mainStruct(:).field(1:1000)` of course, as Daniel points out, your function would have to be vectorized

Comment: @marcowassmer I did not get you, you mean an array, each element in the array is a struct ?

Comment: @Daniel myfunction accepts a vector as input, such as [1,2,3,4,5], single row.

Comment: @GeekCat, yes thats what i mean

Comment: @marcowassmer: Did you try the code? You can't index a comma separated list.

Comment: @Daniel why comma separated list? ...oh wait see what you mean. But you can sourround it with  `{}` to get a cell array and work with that

Comment: @marcowassmer: And a cell array requires iteration to index the elements -> no vectorisation.

Comment: @Daniel you can do a cell2mat, but yes its not much help here

Answer (score 0):

Having a function `myfunction` which requires to be called for each vector individually, you can not vectorize the loop. You can only iterate. You could use `arrayfun` which allows you to write it in one line, but it is slower.

```
result=arrayfun(@(x)myfunction(x.field(1:1000)),mainStruct)
```

For loops in MATLAB are typically (one of) the fastest possibility to iterate. Only avoid them when iteration is not required. In this case, with `myfunction` not being vectorized, you need iteration.

Comment: I tried struct2array(mainStruct), it changed my struct of struct into a very big Char array, completely messed up..

Comment: `struct2array` might be a good choice for a function which allows you to input all data at once in a vectorized way, but you told it is not possible. Not sure what you try to do!