# Apply a function in each tensor slice

Tags: matlab

Suppose we have an 3-D array (tensor) and we want to apply in each slice a function, e.g., `myFun = @(x)mean(x)`. Is there any way to do this without `for` loop using build-in functions (possibly with`bsxfun`, or `arrayfun`, or `accumarray`)?

**For loop example:**

```
inputA = rand(10,5,20);
for sl = 1:size(A,3)
   inputB = myFun(inputA(:,:,sl));  
end
```

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
`inputB = arrayfun(@(iterSlice) myFun(inputA(:,:,iterSlice), 1:size(inputA,3))`

<sup>PS: I would like to mention, that the handler function applied is more complicated in each slice, `mean` was an example included in the handler function.</sup>

Comment: Same issue [like in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940500/vectorize-accelerate-looping-through-a-struct-of-struct-in-matlab), you have to rewrite `myFun` to accept 3d input arguments. If this is not possible, a for loop is the fastest choice.

Comment: I do not want to do this in `z`-direction but per slice. So why should I accept a `3d` input?

Comment: You already chose the fastest way to iterate. The only way to further improve the performance would be to get rid of the individual function calls.

Comment: `basxfun` accepts only built-ins as function arguments, `arrayfun` is slower than the `for` statement in the latest MATLAB versions, `accumarray` doesn't really make sense, at least not to me. So I'd say: take Daniel's advice.

Comment: `arrayfun` is said to be slow. If you are looking for performance, you can use `parfor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for loop is already the best possibility to iterate. The only way to further improve the performance is to get rid of the iteration and have a single function call of `myFun` which processes all data in a vectorized way. For your example function that very simple:

```
myFun=@(x)permute(mean(x,1),[3,2,1])
```

Now it accepts 3d inputs and in the rows you find the results of the previous iterative code. You have to modify your function, there is no generic wrapper on top which can do this for you.

Regarding your edit: `arrayfun` is [known to be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why)

Comment: Thanks for answering, the function I applied is more complicated in each slice, `mean` was an example included in a handler function . So, any changes helpful.

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no generic wrapper which can be put on top of your existing function. You have to modify your function to vectorize it.